# Shower caulk won't dry

Tags: shower, caulk, sealant

We recently added new glass doors to our shower, and finished the job by sealing the track. The caulk we have is specifically for bathrooms (Red Devil), and the instructions say to keep it dry for 72 hours. On Day 4 I used the shower, but when I was done sections of the clear caulk had turned back to white due to the water. Clearly it hasn't fully cured yet.

Will this caulk ever dry, or is it ruined now and needs to be replaced? How long do I really need to let it dry before it's safe to use?

Comment: So it went from white to clear (it dried)  after 2 days, but then went from clear back to white after getting wet on the 4th day? Maybe try another brand that is 100% silicone.

Comment: "Clear extrudes white and turns clear within 2 weeks." – https://www.amazon.com/Red-Devil-0405-DuraGuard-Siliconized/dp/B000NHNWK0 ... 72 hours? Most I've seen is 48, and never anything about 2 weeks. Why is this stuff weird? "*Siliconized Acrylic Caulk*" - yeah, IDC for what room it's called as long as it's 100% silicon.

Comment: I'd wouldn't use it for like the next week; maybe you'll get lucky. Also, put as much heat and as little humidity in there as possible for the time being.

Comment: If it is firm and did not wash away or turn mushy when it got wet, you should be ok. With similar products I have seen the change to clear take weeks, but the caulk was fit to put in service. NOTE- when I have used similar products, it was not in a shower or bath where significant water contact is common; I never use anything but 100% silicone for that, and your product is *not* 100% silicone.

Comment: Try a hairdryer?

Comment: @Mazura The tube we got (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Red-Devil-10-1-oz-Clear-Premium-Kitchen-and-Bath-with-Stain-Block-Caulk-0757/202261803) doesn't even say what it's made of, so that maybe should have been a warning sign...

Comment: It says it's paintable. That tells you it's not 100%. ... "you should wait longer to see if it is just not fully cured" – [Is it normal for acrylic caulk to dissolve?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25214/is-it-normal-for-acrylic-caulk-to-dissolve)